# Google Tag Manager: how can I send dataLayer puhes from dataLayerB to dataLayerA?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, event-listener, google-datalayer

I have a page where `dataLayer` is named as `"dataLayerA"`, and the GTM is set to work with that `dataLayer`. The problem is that all the `dataLayer` pushes send to another `dataLayer`, say `"dataLayerB"`.

For example:

`dataLayerB.push({'event':'foo', 'abc':'def'})` instead of 
`dataLayerA.push({'event':'foo', 'abc':'def'})`

The result is that my GTM can't read this events.

So, I need a way to push to `dataLayerA` everything that is pushed to `dataLayerB` every time a `dataLayerB.push` happen.

I guess I should add some kind of event listener to `dataLayerB` (as a custom `html` tag to fire on `pageview`) that pushes to `dataLayerA` the same things that developer has just pushed to `dataLayerB`.

Thanks for help,
Giulio

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dataLayerBPush = dataLayerB.push;

dataLayerB.push = function(obj) {
  dataLayerBPush(obj);
  dataLayerA.push(obj);
}
```